# Windows 7 not seeing specific WiFi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection

I have a strange behavior under Windows 7.

I installed Mac OS X and Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro and can see my home Wifi under Mac OS X without any problems and connect to it just fine.

When I boot under Windows, I can see all the neighboring WiFis but not my own at all.

Did anyone else experience that? Any hints on what to do?

Comment: It sounded like you are using Bootcamp. You should mention that in your question. Also, you should include the model of your MacBookPro. As well as the make and model of your WiFi Router/AP. Along with any special configuration such as band / channel that you modified from default.

Answer (score 3):

1. connect with an ethernet cable.
2. log in to the router's admin settings.
3. change the channel that the wireless is broadcasting on.
4. save the settings, resetting the router.
5. when reset is complete look for the network again.
6. repeat steps 2 - 5 if still not showing up.
7. when ssid shows up connect & remove ethernet cable

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect the router via wired? Did it use to work before OSX?

You could, just in case, reset the router using the paper-clip method (if applicable to your model).

If that doesn't help, this [thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=700208) recommends using the latest
[Broadcom Wireless LAN Driver for Microsoft Windows 7](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=ob-83617-1&lang=en&cc=us&mode=5&).

Comment: I can connect with a cable and everything works fine. I used it fine with Win7 before and still using it with another laptop. I will try to reset the router, although I feel it is more towards the Win7 side...

Comment: Might be. But one step at a time.

Comment: Ok tried that and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Also tried to remove the device and associated driver but it did nothing new. Home WIFI is still not visible nor accessible, even by giving SSID and password...

Comment: Added another possibility (maybe a shot in the dark).

Comment: Could it be that the wifi signal is 802.11n and that the installed Windows 7 driver does not support it?

Comment: I would say it has nothing to do with your router or win7, but your virtual software your using? Win7 supports n series wifi. OR are you dual booting?

Answer (score 0):

Some WiFi channels are prohibited in some countries. Some drivers are aware of this and allow you to choose location and let them keep you on the safe side of the law; such a driver may hide networks that are illegal according to its settings. In effect two different drivers may present you two slightly different sets of available networks.

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels#Interference_concerns) contains some tables. For 2.4 GHz WiFi (802.11b/g/n) these are allowed channels:

- in North America: channels 1..11;
- in Japan: channels 1..13, 14 with restriction;
- elsewhere: channels 1..13.

This is just a simplified example; refer to the linked Wiki page for details.

So if your Mac OS X wireless network card driver "thinks" you're in Europe (or it doesn't care) and your Windows WiFi driver "thinks" you're in the USA, and if your own network uses channel 12 or 13 -- then you may experience these symptoms you described.

To fix this, check driver settings in Windows. Alternatively reconfigure your own WiFi to use a channel from the set 1..11; this should make it visible regardless of regional setting in any WiFi driver.