# Why does my computer detect all wifi networks but not my home network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1, wireless-router

I have a rather peculiar problem with my Lenovo M30-70 80h8 notebook, which runs on Windows 8.1.
The computer does not detect my home wifi network (unless a repeater is used), but it detects all other surrounding wifi networks.
I have already taken the following steps solve the problem:

1. Restarted wifi router
2. Reconfigured the ssid of the wifi
3. Deactivated/Reactivated Wifi card on laptop
4. Deinstalled/Reinstalled Wifi card drivers on laptop
5. Ran Live-Ubuntu instead of Windows. => Can detect wifi with Ubuntu.

All other devices (tablet, phone, etc.) detect and connect to the wifi without a problem.
The network is not hidden, but protected.
I have a wifi repeater half way down the hall. The laptop finds the wifi, if that repeater is active, but the connection is poor, because the repeater is far away. So it finds the wifi signal from the repeater, but not the signal coming from the original router.
The router was given to me by my internet provider.
The computer used to detect the wifi, but stopped about a month ago.

Given this information I think there is probably something wrong with the windows wireless configuration, but I have no clue what could be the problem.

Does anybody have an idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean by it doesn’t “detect” the WiFi? Do you mean it doesn’t show up in the list of nearby networks? Is this an older laptop? Does it support 5Ghz wireless-N? Perhaps you have disabled the 2.4Ghz band on your router or it doesn’t support simultaneous dual-band. Therefore your laptop can’t “see” the WiFi but your newer devices can.

Comment: Please see if [this](https://superuser.com/a/1309280/432690) helps.

Comment: Yes, it does not show up in the list of near by networks. The router uses both 2.4 and 5 GHz. The laptop is about 3 years old. Most  other devices are about as old as the laptop.

Comment: @Kamil: It is unlikely to be a channel issue, because it is never detected, but the channels change often.

Comment: Check if the router has added the computer name to the blacklist.